BY Google sheets column in a query SELECT statement
I have found a bug when using google sheets where the QUERY statement returns an error when I include the column BY in the query for example using a cell formula :
=query(large_data_range,"Select AZ,BY,BZ WHERE D LIKE '%something'",1)
the QUERY syntax cannot distinguish between the word BY and the column BY in the SELECT statement and the query above reports a parse error.
Is there a syntax which can include column BY?
I was expecting that the SELECT statement would be able to recognise BY as a sheets column rather than a 'SELECT BY' request. Currently I use a clunky workaround to avoid column BY such that the query range is not limited to columns between A and BX.
I believe that the QUERY syntax cannot distinguish between the word BY and the sheet column BY in the SELECT statement. Is there a syntax which I could use in this case?

Since BY is a reserved word, you need to back quote it for column use...
`BY`


